# make finds fortran 77 files but not fortran 90 files

Tags: c++, makefile, fortran

I am having problems compiling a mixed C++/fortran90 code using make. If I instead use a fortran77 code for the subroutine, I have no problems compiling.

The structure of the file system:

```
~/src/working/:
  main.cpp
  Makefile

~/src/lib/:
  f77library.f
  f90library.f90
  cpplibrary.cpp

~/src/headers/:
  cpplibrary.h
```

The makefile looks like the following:

```
VPATH = ../headers/:../lib/

F77 = gfortran
FC = gfortran
CXX = g++

FCFLAGS = -I/home/user/src/headers/     #These may be redundant with VPATH
FFLAGS = -I/home/user/src/headers/
CXXFLAGS = -I/home/user/src/headers/

main77 = main.o f77library.o cpplibrary.o
main90 = main.o f90library.o cpplibrary.o


main77 : $(main77)
    $(CXX) -o main77 $(main77) -lgfortran

main90 : $(main90)
    $(CXX) -o main90 $(main90) -lgfortran

main77.o : main77.cpp cpplibrary.h
main90.o : main90.cpp cpplibrary.h
cpplibrary : cpplibrary.cpp cpplibrary.h
f77library : f77library.f
f90library : f90library.f90
```

Each fortran file contains exactly the same subroutines and each is a standalone file. If I do the compiling by hand it works just fine, e.g.,

```
gfortran -c ../lib/f90library.f90
g++ -c ../lib/cpplibrary.cpp -I../headers/
g++ -c main90.cpp -I../headers/
g++ -o main90 main90.o f90library.o cpplibrary.o
```

When I compile the f77 using the makefile: `make main77` it compiles fine. When I try `make main90` however, I get the following error message

```
g++ -o main90 main90.o f90library.o cpplibrary.o -lgfortran
g++: f90library.o: No such file or directory
```

In short, everything is identical between the f90 and f77 versions, and there should be no compilation errors. Why can't `make` recognize that there is a .f90 file it needs to compile in the lib directory?

Comment: You list four commands when you do it by hand, and only the fourth when you use Make; does Make execute the first three?

Comment: @Beta Sorry, yes, make compiled main.o and cpplibrary.o fine (should have included that output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, Make does not provide an implicit rule for compiling .f90 files. But you could still achieve what you want, e.g., by adding a pattern rule

```
%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $<
```

Comment: Missing `.` in the target. Also, using the built-in `FC` and `FFLAGS` variables is unlikely to be helpful if they expect to be able to compile both f77 and f90 sources.